# An error in integration of a Web hook to API.AI

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I'm trying to implement an app according to the stages written in:
https://developers.google.com/actions/get-started/

I follow all stages, but there is some problem with connecting the Webhook to the app.
When trying to operate the app and connect to the Webhook, I get the following error in the json file:

"status": {
    "code": 206,
    "errorType": "partial_content",
    "errorDetails": "Webhook call failed. Error: Webhook response was empty."
  },

Does anyone know what might be the problem?

Comment: Please add more details (e.g. the URL and logs of your webhook) - It might help to see what is going wrong. My hunch, is that your webhook is not returning any JSON response.

Comment: Thanks to your question, I noticed that there was a white space in the URL I copied for the webhook in the Fulfillment tab in API.AI. I erased this white space and now it works! Thanks a lot

Comment: Great :) Happy it was helpful!